UI stuck when loading images
I'm building a simple Images desktop app and it going well.
The app gets my images from folder showing them in ItemsControl. The page layout is string Key - (MM)YYYY and Items it StorageItem Class.
<ItemsControl x:Name="test_control">

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                
                <!-- Display the Key (Year and Month) -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,10" />


                <GridView 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    RightTapped="GridView_RightTapped"
                    DoubleTapped="GridView_DoubleTapped">

                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="20" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>

                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding FullPath}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Image Height="90" Width="90" Source="{Binding Icon}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ProgressRing 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    Visibility="{Binding ProgressBarVisiable}"
                                    Value="{Binding Value}"
                                    IsIndeterminate="False"
                                    Height="25"
                                    Width="25"/>
                                <FontIcon HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Glyph="{Binding StatusFont}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                </GridView>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>

The Icon property is BitmapImage.
This work perfect but when I have a lot of items, the page stuck and wait to load all the images.
MediaPage.cs
test.ItemsSource = App.AllImages;

MainPage.cs
App.AllImages = new ObservableCollection<MediaDynamicView>();
PublicMethods.GetAllImages(AllImages);

MediaDynamicView.cs
public class MediaDynamicView : DynamicView<ImageItem>
{
    public DateTime YearMonth { get; set; }

//...
}

DynamicView<T>
public class DynamicView<T>
{
    private string _key;
    private ObservableCollection<T> _items;

    public string Key 
    { 
        get { return _key; }
        set { _key = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<T> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set{ _items = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    //...
}

ImageItem.cs
// more properties...

        public virtual BitmapImage Icon
        {
            get { return _icon; }
            set { _icon = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

I know that the Icon property loaded before MediaPage.cs showing this in the GridView
what should I do to make it Async?

You might need to share code how you are populating Items for GridView. Also, not sure why you are wrapping the GridView with an ItemsControl.

@AndrewKeepCoding the GridView inside ItemsControl wat the best way to wrap the items.
I don't have much more code about the UI but I'll add now code for classes

For how long is the UI stuck? How many and how large images are we talking about? Have you done any profiling or other measurements to confirm that it is actually the image loading that takes time? Making something async will not help if it was not the problem in the first place.

@JonasH The images are thumbnails, I know that the loading images are stuck because I am loading the images to BitmapImage in PublicMethods.GetAllImages().
This works fine with 50 - 100 images, but when I get 500 images, the UI is stuck for 10 seconds to load the images to the UI. I want the UI to show a white background and change it to the Icon property when it loads the images. Like Google Photos

But have you measured?!  If you suspect PublicMethods.GetAllImages(), stick a stopwatch in it, if you are right you have wasted a minute or so, if you are wrong you might save days of work. Or even better, run a performance profiler.  It is not that uncommon for UIs to get slow because it is updated for each new item, and the updates get slower the more items there are. The way to solve that kind of problem is virtualization or batch updates.

@JonasH I don't know how to do that with virtualization. I've looked for it and didn't find something. I know there is something called lazy ListView but I don't know how to create one.

Start by getting familiar with stopwatch and profiling. If we are talking about 500 high resolution images you are probably right that you need async loading. But measuring and profiling are still invaluable tools. I have not used WinUI3, so I'm not familiar with how it does virtualization.

@AndrewKeepCoding I updated the code
